# Applying binary search within SQL statement using Java?

Tags: java, sql, binary-search

I'm using Java and SQL but I need to do an SQL query in a table with 8000 rows.
So to make the process faster I've decided to use the binary search technique.

It would be easy to apply it if my data is an array. However in this case I should enter each row of data in a Java array and that wouldn't make any difference as the SQL would pass all the rows.

below is the statement that would search in about 8000 rows. So is there a way to apply binary search within the SQL statement?

```
// Executing SQL & retrieve data into ResultSet
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT ID, book_name, author FROM Books WHERE filter LIKE \'%" + word + "%\' ORDER BY book_name ASC");
```

Comment: You're not making any sense. Binary search requires the data to be ordered by the search criteria. Since you `ORDER BY book_name`, does that mean you're searching for a book by name? If so, simply write `WHERE book_name = ?` and supply a value. If that is slow, because the database then scans the entire table, create an `INDEX` on `book_name`. An `INDEX` is basically equivalent to making a binary search available to the database for the indexed column.

Comment: @Andreas: a LIKE condition using `%foo%` can't use a regular index on essentially all DBMS. To support a condition like that a different type of index is needed (e.g. a trigram index in Postgres)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I know, but you can't use binary search for a `LIKE '%foo%'` either, and the `LIKE` is not against the column of the `ORDER BY`, so since binary search requires sorted data, I simply couldn't fathom how OP might have *"decided to use the binary search technique"* for a `filter LIKE '%foo%'` condition. I'd be really curious to see how OP would have applied a binary search to that, if that was the intention. As such, I rejected/ignored the `LIKE` as being the what OP is asking about, hence why I'm *assuming* that OP was doing a `WHERE book_name = ?`.